# Hide a list except the selected list option

Tags: jquery, list, show-hide

I need some help with a nested list, what I want to do is to show one of the list options and hide the rest of the list,  a great example that I saw was in the filesonic.com languages selector or netlog status change in the header.

```
<ul class="links">
  <li class="us">United States</li>
  <li class="canada">Canada</li>
  <li class="france">France</li>
  <li class="china">China</li>
  <li class="englande">England</li>
```

United States is the default but when someone click on France, the rest of the list will hide and show will show.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this will do the trick:

```
// Initially hide everything apart from the active list item
$('ul li.active').show()
  .siblings().hide();

// Set up a click handler that will show all the list items when the active
// element is clicked on, or makes the clicked on item the active item and hides
// the rest.
$('ul li').click(function(){
  var $parent=$(this).parent();
  if ($parent.is('.open')){
    $parent.removeClass('open');
    $(this).addClass('active')
      .siblings().removeClass('active').hide();
  }
  else {
    $parent.addClass('open').children().show();
  }
});
```

Here is a working JSBIN example: http://jsbin.com/onile4

Hope this helps!

Comment: this looks great except that I want the selected/active list option to be on top of the list like the above example work... I really appreciate it Stony...

Comment: Hi, you mean you want the selected item to be moved to the top of the list?

Comment: OK, try this: http://jsbin.com/onile4/3, the only change is this line:`$(this).detach().prependTo($parent);` which detaches the list item that was clicked on and reinserts it at the top of the list of items. Detach is used because it keeps the event handlers intact. If this answers your question, please mark it as so! Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

```
$(function(){
  $('ul.links > li').click(function(){
      $('ul.links > li').fadeOut();
      $(this).fadeIn();
  });
});
```

Comment: jsfiddle examples always work better so I can make changes and test myself, thanks for answering.

Comment: This is not a complete answer, it doesn't let you click on the selected item to redisplay the whole list.

Answer (score 0):

If 'us' was selected, you could:

```
$('ul > li[class!=us]').css('display', 'none');
```

Answer (score 0):

A quick n dirty sample with comments(you can improvize it based on your needs):

Working example @ http://jsfiddle.net/dCZpx/

```
<div style="width: 100px">
    <div style="background-color: #FFDDEE" id="country">Click here to Select Country</div>
    <ul class="links">   
        <li class="us">United States</li>   
        <li class="canada">Canada</li>   
        <li class="france">France</li>   
        <li class="china">China</li>   
        <li class="englande">England</li> 
    </ul>
    <script type="text/javascript">    
        $(function(){

            //Bind the Click handler for the box that displays the selected Country
            $("#country").click(function(){
                //When the Country Box is clicked, show all the country names except the selected one
                $(".links li").not("." + $(this).data("current")).show("slow"); 
            });

            //First Hide all the Country Names list 
            $(".links li").hide();

            //Bind OnClick handler to all list elements which are children of .links
            $(".links li").click(function(){
                //Set the currently selected country in the data attribute of the #country element.
                $("#country").data("current", $(this).attr("class"));
                //Set the text of the #country div to the selected country name
                $("#country").text($(this).text());
                //Now hide all the list elements 
                $(".links li").hide("slow");
            });
               $(".links li.us").click();
        });
    </script> 
</div>
```

Comment: this works for me but I wanted the United states to be the selected one without "Click here to Select country" option

Comment: @Ralph: Updated the post to select US by default. All you need to do is call $(".links li.us").click(); in the document.ready handler at the end.

Comment: i am realizing some issues, like when u click on the selected list again or the list doesn't close when the mouse click somewhere else... any chance u might look at these again? thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like:

```
if ($('.selected').length){
    return false;
}
else {
    $('.links li:first').addClass('selected');
}
$('.links li').click(
    function(){
        $('.selected').removeClass('selected');
        $(this).addClass('selected');
    });
```

coupled with the CSS:

```
li {
    display: none;
}

li.selected {
    display: list-item;
}

ul:hover li {
    display: list-item;
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/PuBBx/1/).